# INSERT INTO from two temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 temp table with data in each one.

And i want to insert data in a real table using data from both temp tables

i just tried something like that but cant get it to work !

```
INSERT INTO list_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@listid)+'.dbo.members_optout_snapshot(listid,optout,nbreEmail,nbreSMS,date_snapshot)
SELECT listid, optout, nbEmail, date FROM #tmpOptout
UNION ALL
SELECT listid, optout, nbSMS, date FROM #tmpOptoutSMS
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: you will required `Dynamic Query` if your DB name is dynamic

Comment: Do you need to use the ''INSERT INTO list_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@listid)+'....." or can you simply  type the database name? if not I beleive you need to have a look at how to execute a dynamic query

Comment: I'm using this in dynamic query already ! i don't get any error ! it just doesn't insert anything !

Comment: no you are not ! This is not Dynamic Query. Refer to http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: Sorry, i didn't give you all the code ! but trust me it's in a dynamic query with an @SQL variable and a EXEC(@SQL) !

Comment: then please do inlcude the complete query so that we can better understand your issue. There are 2 answer posted already that is based on your half dynamic query

Comment: @Squirrel is right, what you have given us isn't Dynamic SQL. If that is what you have, then post the **full** SQL. And, also, why have you not provided us with the error? Any answers you get will be based on the **incomplete** information you have provided, and thus you *could* just be wasting the time of the volunteers trying to help you.

Comment: if your issue is not `dynamic query`, i would guess it is column list in the insert does not matches with the select list. You have 5 in `INSERT` vs 4 in `SELECT`

Comment: I hadn't spotted that. I would suggest that that is the answer, @Squirrel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a variable as part, or as a replacement, of an object's name. For example, the following fails:

```
DECLARE @object sysname = N'Columns';
SELECT *
FROM sys.@object;
```

You need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @object sysname = N'Columns';
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM sys.' + QUOTENAME(@object) + N';';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

For what you have, that would mean something like:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'
INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME('list_' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@listid))  + N'.dbo.members_optout_snapshot (listid,
                                                optout,
                                                nbreEmail,
                                                nbreSMS,
                                                date_snapshot)
SELECT listid,
       optout,
       nbEmail,
       date
FROM #tmpOptout
UNION ALL
SELECT listid,
       optout,
       nbSMS,
       date
FROM #tmpOptoutSMS;';
PRINT @SQL; --Your Best friend
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

*Note 1: This is untested. Use your Best friend to help you debug.*

*Note2: Don't declare a `varchar` without a length! I have guessed `varchar(10)` here.*

*Note 3: This is based on the OP's original incomplete question. Squirrel has noticed that the number of columns in the `INSERT` and `SELECT` clause do not match (5 and 4 columns respectively); thus this query will still fail. I am not addressing that point though, as the question I am answering is in regards to the original format, and that the OP appears to be trying to use variables as object names. I will leave Squirrel to address the issue he has noticed in an answer.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable

```
declare @query varchar(MAX)='INSERT INTO list_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@listid)+'.dbo.members_optout_snapshot(listid,optout,nbreEmail,nbreSMS,date_snapshot)
SELECT listid, optout, nbEmail, date FROM #tmpOptout
UNION ALL
SELECT listid, optout, nbSMS, date FROM #tmpOptoutSMS'

execute( @query)
```

Comment: I recommend against `CONVERT(VARCHAR,@listid)`; you should always declare the length of a `varchar`. It's ***implied*** that `@listid` isn't a varchar (maybe an `int` or something), however, I also still recommend against simple raw string concatenation. Using something like `QUOTENAME` is by far always a safer option and just good practice..